# Convert Java object to Json request with alias property

Tags: java, json, rest

I need to convert the following java class to json string with different property name :

```
public class Company {

private String companyYCode;

private String companyName;

 getxx and setxx
```

}

I need this as a json string

{"y-code":"CICPK1214131231","company_name":"Some company" }

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/ ..  you need to use Gson library to convert obj to Json ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, i think the simple way for you is using Jackson library for custom the json properties.
If you use maven, you can add dependency into your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And in your model class, just use the annotation JsonProperty to config the value you want:

```
public class Company {

    @JsonProperty ("y-code")
    private String companyYCode;

    @JsonProperty ("company_name")
    private String companyName;
}
```

With that, when you parse your object Company to Json, your json string will has properties which your want:

{"y-code":"CICPK1214131231","company_name":"Some company" }

Comment: @SebastienLe The above thing is not working for me.Still I am getting the same values companyName, companyYCode Like this: {"companyYCode":"CICPK1214131231","companyName":"Some company"}. Don't know why that thing is happening.And I added the 2.7.0 version of the jackson dependency.Please help me to get out of this.Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method

```
public String toJson() {
    JSONObjectBuilder json = new JSONObjectBuilder();
    /*
     add 'whatever you like - content' here
    */ 
    return json.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson library...

```
public class Company {

@JsonProperty ("y-code")
private String companyYCode;

@JsonProperty ("company_name")
private String companyName;

 getxx and setxx
}
```

Answer (score 0):

main class...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class ObjToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Company user = new Company();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), user);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(user));

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

  }

}
```

POJO :

```
public class Company {

  private String companyYCode="CICPK1214131231";
  private String companyName="Some company";
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [companyYCode=" + companyYCode + ", companyName=" + companyName + "]";
    }
    public String getCompanyYCode() {
      return companyYCode;
    }
    public void setCompanyYCode(String companyYCode) {
      this.companyYCode = companyYCode;
    }
    public String getCompanyName() {
      return companyName;
    }
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
      this.companyName = companyName;
    }
}
```